BMP format Image convolution in C++
Is there any way to optimize this image convolution algorithm in C++:
void convolution(const Image& input, const std::vector<float>& kernel, Image& output) {
    int kernelSize = static_cast<int>(std::sqrt(kernel.size()));
    int kernelRadius = kernelSize / 2;

#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
    for (int y = 0; y < input.height; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < input.width; ++x) {
            float sumRed = 0, sumGreen = 0, sumBlue = 0;

            for (int ky = -kernelRadius; ky <= kernelRadius; ++ky) {
                for (int kx = -kernelRadius; kx <= kernelRadius; ++kx) {
                    int imgX = std::max(0, std::min(input.width - 1, x + kx));
                    int imgY = std::max(0, std::min(input.height - 1, y + ky));

                    int kernelIndex = (ky + kernelRadius) * kernelSize + (kx + kernelRadius);
                    sumBlue += input.pixels[imgY * input.width + imgX].blue * kernel[kernelIndex];
                    sumGreen += input.pixels[imgY * input.width + imgX].green * kernel[kernelIndex];
                    sumRed += input.pixels[imgY * input.width + imgX].red * kernel[kernelIndex];
                }
            }

            output.pixels[y * input.width + x].blue = static_cast<uint8_t>(std::max(0.0f, std::min(255.0f, sumBlue)));
            output.pixels[y * input.width + x].green = static_cast<uint8_t>(std::max(0.0f, std::min(255.0f, sumGreen)));
            output.pixels[y * input.width + x].red = static_cast<uint8_t>(std::max(0.0f, std::min(255.0f, sumRed)));
        }
    }
} 

I need to compare this algorithm with another or simply optimize it and conduct the comparison. Are there any suggestions for algorithm or code improvements, as well as for comparative analysis with other algorithms?

what do you want to optimize? Readability? Speed? Memory usage? ... ? You cannot get it all, hence you need to specific what you want

Yes use an image processing library (https://learnopencv.com/image-filtering-using-convolution-in-opencv/). In the end optimization is not always about adding more threads, but more about optimizing cache usage so a SIMD approach might actually be faster. First thing you should do is to use a profiler and MEASURE your current performance to find the bottlenecks in your code (and hardware)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai And also that :)

Nice thoughts,
gonna consider them.
Thank you.

One option used in some convolvers where the support region of the kernel is relatively small is to pad the source image array with kernelRadius of zero lines above and columns at the end of each line so that the tests can be eliminated from the inner loop. The alternative is to special case test just the borders within kernelRadius of any edge, which one if preferable depends on the size of the pointspread function.  These days branch predictors are so good it may not matter. Profile it to see where it spends most time and how much faster it might be without the tests.
